# Compute iterations until gas limit would be reached, then revert to before gas limit reached

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, gas

I have a contract doing a lot of multiplication & addition.
Something like:

```
for (uint index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
      let numAdders = adders[index];
      if (numAdders > 0) {
        added = numAdders * index;
        tokens[senders] = tokens[sender] + added;
     } 
}
```

A) I see the opcode cost is 3 for add, 5 for multiply... so it looks like I'm never in danger of running out of gas for this, right?

B) If the 10 in the above code was dynamic, could I have the contract iterate through index up until gas limit was reached (or some gas limit threshhold set by the caller of the function passed as a param) and then commit all state changes up to that point + store a state variable to know where to continue next function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, but you can manage gas consumption and respond accordingly.

Your big cost is going to be SSTORE and to a lessor extent, SREAD. While the computations are somewhat trivial reading the state is non-trivial and setting the state is quite expensive.

If I'm not mistaken, `msg.gas` will give the contract visibility into the remaining gas. Importantly, the contract needs to have enough gas left to perform any wind-down steps so everything finishes before the available gas is exhausted.

Generally, unbounded loops are an anti-pattern. Instead of introducing unwanted complexity into the contract in support of an interative process, consider designing the function to deal with one iteration at a time so you have a consistent gas cost at any scale. A client would attend to interation and send multiple transactions.

There is an implication that you would need to leave the contract in a valid state every step of the way. That takes a little getting used to.

Hope it helps.